# How to calculate repeated array elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a bit puzzled on how to achieve this and hopefully someone can help me figure it out!

I have documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong("1213477"),
    "players" : [
        {
            "acc_id" : 1,
            "cards" : [
                {
                    "id" : 112,
                    "l" : 3
                },
                {
                    "id" : 121,
                    "l" : 6
                },
                {
                    "id" : 123
                },
                {
                    "id" : 126
                },
                {
                    "id" : 130,
                    "l" : 8
                },
                {
                    "id" : 139,
                    "l" : 6
                },
                {
                    "id" : 103,
                    "l" : 6
                },
                {
                    "id" : 111
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "acc_id" : 52,
            "cards" : [
                {
                    "id" : 112,
                    "l" : 2
                },
                {
                    "id" : 121,
                    "l" : 5
                },
                {
                    "id" : 123
                },
                {
                    "id" : 132
                },
                {
                    "id" : 139,
                    "l" : 5
                },
                {
                    "id" : 104,
                    "l" : 2
                },
                {
                    "id" : 108,
                    "l" : 8
                },
                {
                    "id" : 108,
                    "l" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, there are two players in this game, and each player has 8 cards selected. I want to run some query and find how many people use the same exact cards. In the end I should be able to have a list of the most popular decks. (each card has a specific use)

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undarstood it well, the [mongodb aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/aggregation-introduction/) along with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipelines and  [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator should work for you.
So, based on the following collection (pretty like you have posted above):

```
db.game_players.insert({    
    "players" : [
        {
            "acc_id" : 1,
            "cards" : [
                {"id" : 112, "l" : 3 }, 
                {"id" : 121, "l" : 6 }, 
                {"id" : 123 },
                {"id" : 126 },
                {"id" : 130, "l" : 8},
                {"id" : 139, "l" : 6 },
                {"id" : 103, "l" : 6 },
                {"id" : 111 }
            ]
        },
        {
            "acc_id" : 52,
            "cards" : [
                {"id" : 112, "l" : 2 },
                {"id" : 121, "l" : 5 },
                {"id" : 123 },
                {"id" : 132 },
                {"id" : 139, "l" : 5 },
                {"id" : 104, "l" : 2 },
                {"id" : 108, "l" : 8 },
                {"id" : 108, "l" : 1 }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

#### Step 1: Unwind the players:

```
db.game_players.aggregate([{$unwind: '$players'}])
```

It deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. The output is something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580d792676d77d5928600787"),
    "players" : {
        "acc_id" : 1,
        "cards" : [
            {
                "id" : 112,
                "l" : 3
            },
            {
                "id" : 121,
                "l" : 6
            },
            {
                "id" : 123
            },
            {
                "id" : 126
            },
            {
                "id" : 130,
                "l" : 8
            },
            {
                "id" : 139,
                "l" : 6
            },
            {
                "id" : 103,
                "l" : 6
            },
            {
                "id" : 111
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580d792676d77d5928600787"),
    "players" : {
        "acc_id" : 52,
        "cards" : [
            {
                "id" : 112,
                "l" : 2
            },
            {
                "id" : 121,
                "l" : 5
            },
            {
                "id" : 123
            },
            {
                "id" : 132
            },
            {
                "id" : 139,
                "l" : 5
            },
            {
                "id" : 104,
                "l" : 2
            },
            {
                "id" : 108,
                "l" : 8
            },
            {
                "id" : 108,
                "l" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see now each player is an document rather than an array element.

#### Step 2: Group by cards

In the next stage we gonna to add the group pipeline grouping by cards:

```
db.game_players.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$players'
}, {
    '$group': {
        _id: {
            'card': '$players.cards.id'
        }
    }
}]) {
    "_id": {
        "card": [112, 121, 123, 132, 139, 104, 108, 108]
    }
} {
    "_id": {
        "card": [112, 121, 123, 126, 130, 139, 103, 111]
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{ "_id" : { "card" : [ 112, 121, 123, 132, 139, 104, 108, 108 ] } }
{ "_id" : { "card" : [ 112, 121, 123, 126, 130, 139, 103, 111 ] } }
```

Notice that `cards` key was added to grouping. That's because we need to reference it on the next stage.

#### Step 3: unwind and group again and sum the popular (repeated?) cards

```
db.game_players.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$players'
}, {
    '$group': {
        _id: {
            'card': '$players.cards.id'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$_id.card'
}, {
    '$group': {
        _id: '$_id.card',
        'cards_count': {
            '$sum': 1
        }
    }
}])
```

At the moment we have total count for each cards. See output bellow:

```
{ "_id" : 111, "cards_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 103, "cards_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 126, "cards_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 123, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 108, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 112, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 104, "cards_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 139, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 132, "cards_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 130, "cards_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 121, "cards_count" : 2 }
```

Now you are almost there!

#### Step 4: selecting cards where count is greater than or equals to 2:

```
db.game_players.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$players'
}, {
    '$group': {
        _id: {
            'card': '$players.cards.id'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$_id.card'
}, {
    '$group': {
        _id: '$_id.card',
        'cards_count': {
            '$sum': 1
        }
    }
}, {
    '$match': {
        cards_count: {
            '$gte': 2
        }
    }
}])
```

And the final output is:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 108, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 112, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 139, "cards_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 121, "cards_count" : 2 }
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you for explaining in detail the unwinding process. What I wanted was actually step 2 above and you went further than I needed :) just added a sum and now I can have a count of what kind of deck combinations are popular. Thank you so much, you're the best !